# Mongoose installation failed on Mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This was what I got in my terminal.
I have mongoDB and node.js installed already..
If anyone can help me with this I'll appreciate it a lot!
Thank you...

[image: This is what showed in my terminal]

Comment: Do you have Python installed?

Comment: From what I see in your terminal, I think your installation is successful

Comment: @BidhanA Yes, I do have python

Comment: @Kelsadita Really !?...  how come there's "nodemon: command not found" ..  :( ..

Comment: @pikkuu [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) isn't directly associated with [`mongoose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). To use both, you'll have to `npm install` each of them separately. Also note that `nodemon` should be [installed globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) to be available as a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in your terminal, I think your installation for `mongoose` is successful. And you are staring your application using `nodemon` but I think that is not installed as you are getting an error `nodemon: command not found`. So first you will need to install `nodemon` using,

`npm install -g nodemon`